# What's the word for something that wants/needs your constant attention

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm trying to remember the word for something/someone that requires your constant attention. The word doesn't have to be derogative or negative.

Comment: A distraction, maybe?

Comment: Can you add a sample sentence, with a ___ where the word would go? That will help us figure out the kind of word and connotations you want. (It's also technically [required for single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) questions.)

Comment: you might say "squeaky wheel" referencing the idiom "the squeaky wheel gets the grease"

Comment: There's the adjective "clingy" (negative connotation) for a person

Comment: For a person who demands attention "needy" is sometimes used. It's not a formal term and it's negative.

Comment: Maybe _demanding_?

Answer (score 4):

For a person, you could use **high-maintenance**, though that does tend to have negative overtones.

> Needing a lot of work to keep in good condition.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/high-maintenance

> informal (of a person) demanding a lot of attention. ‘I freely admit
>   to being high-maintenance’ 'Caitlin is our only child and she's very
>   high-maintenance’

Or, simply **demanding**.

> requiring much time, effort, or attention

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demanding

Answer (score 1):

***[Needy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=needy)***

> Requiring attention beyond what is normative. Getting anxious when
>   someone doesn't reply to you on MSN after 15 seconds is being needy.

(Urban Dictionary)

and courtesy of [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/needy):

> Marked by want of affection, attention, or emotional support...

Comment: Though your word does describe someone needing attention, the word does have negative connotations with it, which the OP said they didn't want. Your answer could work as a comment simply mentioning that needy can be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**exigent**

pressing; demanding.
"the exigent demands of her contemporaries' music took a toll on her voice"

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for discovering this thread so late,
but ‘pressing’ is a fitting word.

Pressing: “Requiring quick or immediate action or attention.”